Iteration an object in Python
I am new to python. I am trying to parse some 10-Ks from Edgar using edgartools and sec-parsers module of python. Here is my code -
import pandas as pd
# pip install edgartools
from edgar import *

# Tell the SEC who you are
set_identity("Your Name myemail@outlook.com")

filings = get_filings( form = "10-K", filing_date="2023-12-15:2024-07-16",amendments=False )

filings_df = filings.to_pandas() # all filings info now in a data frame 

filings[5].document.url # to get the url of a individual document


But when I run the following code -
for x in filings:
    filings[x].document.url

The error shows - 'Filing object cannot be interpreted as an integer.
I am not sure why this is happening. I want the result of for loop function above in a list so that I can later use it in sec-parsers like this -
from sec_parsers import Filing, download_sec_filing, set_headers

def print_first_n_lines(text, n):
    lines = text.split('\n')
    for line in lines[:n]:
        print(line)

html = download_sec_filing(filings[6070].document.url) # for example I need the url for filings index 6070

filing = Filing(html)
filing.html

filing.parse() # parses filing
filing.xml


item1c = filing.find_nodes_by_title('item 1c') [0]
item1c_text = filing.get_node_text(item1c)
print_first_n_lines(item1c_text,50)


My goal is to create a data frame for all filings with the text from Item C in 10-K and add this Item C text in filings_df data frame as an additional column. Note that to add the Item C text in  filings_df data frame as a column, we can use CIK and the year variable (from filing_date variable).
Thanks

for x in filings: will iterate over the elements of filings, themselves - you just want to use x in further code, rather than filings[x].

@jasonharper I actually need the url links of all of my filings so that i can use them to download all 10Ks using download_sec_filing function in sec-parsers module.

@jasonharper is corrrect. Use x as in x.document.url.

The issue arises because you're trying to use an integer as an index for your filings list in the for loop, which isn't necessary since filings is already an iterable object. Additionally, the filings object appears to be a list of Filing objects, and you should iterate over the objects directly instead of indexing them.
import pandas as pd
# pip install edgartools
from edgar import *
from sec_parsers import Filing, download_sec_filing, set_headers

# Tell the SEC who you are
set_identity("Your Name myemail@outlook.com")

# Fetch filings
filings = get_filings(form="10-K", filing_date="2023-12-15:2024-07-16", amendments=False)

# Convert filings to a DataFrame
filings_df = filings.to_pandas()

# Create a list to store the Item 1c text
item1c_texts = []

# Iterate over each filing
for filing in filings:
    url = filing.document.url
    cik = filing.cik
    filing_date = filing.filing_date
    
    # Download and parse the filing
    html = download_sec_filing(url)
    sec_filing = Filing(html)
    sec_filing.parse()
    
    # Extract the text for Item 1c
    item1c_nodes = sec_filing.find_nodes_by_title('item 1c')
    if item1c_nodes:
        item1c_text = sec_filing.get_node_text(item1c_nodes[0])
    else:
        item1c_text = None
    
    item1c_texts.append({
        'CIK': cik,
        'Filing Date': filing_date,
        'Item 1c Text': item1c_text
    })

# Create a DataFrame from the Item 1c text data
item1c_df = pd.DataFrame(item1c_texts)

# Merge the Item 1c text DataFrame with the filings DataFrame
filings_df = filings_df.merge(item1c_df, on=['CIK', 'Filing Date'])

# Print the final DataFrame
print(filings_df)

In this code:

You create a list of URLs for all filings using a list comprehension.
You use this list of URLs to download and parse the filings.
You extract the text for "Item 1c" from each filing and store it in a list.
4 . You create a DataFrame from the list of "Item 1c" texts.

This should help you achieve your goal of creating a DataFrame with the text from "Item 1c" in the 10-K filings.

S.Dewett, Hi I have a litte edited my question. I need to add the Item C text in a data frame called filings_df. Can you please shed some light on how I can do this? Actually, when parsing item IC I also need to keep the CIK variable and the filing_date of the document and this will help us to merge the dataset with filings_df. Thanks

Hi, when I try to run code to create a data frame using the for loop function in your code, it shows me an error - list index out of range. Do You have any idea what is going on?

Here are some steps you can take
Convert the filings object to a DataFrame.
Iterate over each filing, extract the URL, download and parse the filing.
Extract the text from "Item 1c".
Add the extracted text as a new column in the filings_df DataFrame.

Updated the answer, that will handle that case as well

Thank You very much. It works perfectly.

@S. Dewett, I see edgartools has a function like tenK = filings[0].obj() to parse. I tried to use some codes like tenK.items, tenK.doc.chunks_for_item,  tenK.doc.chunks_for_item, and tenK.doc.show_items to get Item 1C, but was not successful. Can you please shed some light on it? Thanks

Please ask a new question, as it won't be good practice to edit the code again for the question with a different context

This answer looks like a copy-paste from ChatGPT - https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

@S.Dewett I have posted the question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78773176/how-to-ignore-or-by-pass-instances-that-results-in-nonetype-non-iterable-object. Can you please check? Thanks

for x in filings: iterates the objects contained by filings, not the index into filings. Try
for filing in filings:
    filing.document.url

You already did this with the for loop in your print_first_n_lines function.

The docs from edgartools say: "The filings data is stored in the Filings class as a pyarrow.Table.". Can we still iterate over them with for .. in .. or do we need another way ?

I'm not sure. I don't know what class type is in filings. From your example where you use filings[5], its some sort of container type (maybe even just a list) and its common for a container that indexes to also iterate. So, its just a quess but is a simple thing to try to see if it works.

for x in filings:
    filings[x].document.url

in this code when you iterate over filings, x is a 'filings' object, but then you are trying to use it as index here, filings[x].document.url
due to which you are getting the error, so you can probably just do this
for x in filings:
    x.document.url

