How to ignore or bypass instances that result in NoneType non-iterable object
I am trying to parse a section from 10K in Edgar database, when I run the following code,
# pip install edgartools
import pandas as pd
from edgar import *

# Tell the SEC who you are
set_identity("Your Name youremail@outlook.com")
filings2 = get_filings(form='10-K', amendments=False, 
filing_date="2024-03-01") 

filings2_df = filings2.to_pandas()
# Create a list to store the Item 1c text
item1c_texts = []

# Iterate over each filing
for filing in filings2:
    url = filing.document.url
    cik = filing.cik
    filing_date = filing.header.filing_date,
    reporting_date = filing.header.period_of_report,
    comn = filing.company
    
    # Extract the text for Item 1c
    TenK = filing.obj()

    item1c_text = TenK['Item 1C']
    item1c_texts.append({
        'CIK': cik,
        'Filing Date': str(filing_date),
        'Item 1c Text': item1c_text,
        'url': url,
        'reporting_date': str(reporting_date),
        'comn': comn
    })

# Create a DataFrame from the Item 1c text data
item1c_df = pd.DataFrame(item1c_texts)

I got this error -
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
Cell In[463], line 11
      9 if TenK is not None:
     10     TenK = filing.obj()
---> 11 item1c_text = TenK['Item 1C']
     12 item1c_texts.append({
     13     'CIK': cik,
     14     'Filing Date': str(filing_date),
   (...)
     18     'comn': comn
     19 })
Show Traceback

Is there any way I can bypass the non-iterable NoneType issue? I read about many other NoneType issues in this platform, but none of them is very helpful for me.

It seems that Item_1C is not available for some of them. You can use try/exception to bypass when the value is not found.
for n, filing in enumerate(filings2):
    url = filing.document.url
    cik = filing.cik
    filing_date = filing.header.filing_date,
    reporting_date = filing.header.period_of_report,
    comn = filing.company

    # Extract the text for Item 1c
    TenK = filing.obj()
    
    # Bypass None values
    try:
        item1c_text = TenK['Item 1C']
    except:
        item1c_text = None

    # Append the data to the list
    # item1c_text = TenK['Item 1C']
    item1c_texts.append({
        'CIK': cik,
        'Filing Date': str(filing_date),
        'Item 1c Text': item1c_text,
        'url': url,
        'reporting_date': str(reporting_date),
        'comn': comn
    })

It appears that five of them are missing.
